# Loading two similar scripts twice dosn't work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, sticky

i have this javascript that I called **cookiebar.js**, it shows a sticky bar message for cookies, ([source code](https://github.com/dobarkod/cookie-banner/))

```
(function (context) {
"use strict";
var win = context,
    doc = win.document;
var global_instance_name = "cbinstance";
function contentLoaded(win, fn) {
    var done = false,
        top = true,
        doc = win.document,
        root = doc.documentElement,
        add = doc.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
        rem = doc.addEventListener ? "removeEventListener" : "detachEvent",
        pre = doc.addEventListener ? "" : "on",
        init = function (e) {
            if (e.type == "readystatechange" && doc.readyState != "complete") return;
            (e.type == "load" ? win : doc)[rem](pre + e.type, init, false);
            if (!done && (done = true)) fn.call(win, e.type || e);
        },
        poll = function () {
            try {
                root.doScroll("left");
            } catch (e) {
                setTimeout(poll, 50);
                return;
            }
            init("poll");
        };
    if (doc.readyState == "complete") fn.call(win, "lazy");
    else {
        if (doc.createEventObject && root.doScroll) {
            try {
                top = !win.frameElement;
            } catch (e) {}
            if (top) poll();
        }
        doc[add](pre + "DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
        doc[add](pre + "readystatechange", init, false);
        win[add](pre + "load", init, false);
    }
}
var Cookies = {
    get: function (key) {
        return decodeURIComponent(doc.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
    },
    set: function (key, val, end, path, domain, secure) {
        if (!key || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(key)) {
            return false;
        }
        var expires = "";
        if (end) {
            switch (end.constructor) {
                case Number:
                    expires = end === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + end;
                    break;
                case String:
                    expires = "; expires=" + end;
                    break;
                case Date:
                    expires = "; expires=" + end.toUTCString();
                    break;
            }
        }
        doc.cookie = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(val) + expires + (domain ? "; domain=" + domain : "") + (path ? "; path=" + path : "") + (secure ? "; secure" : "");
        return true;
    },
    has: function (key) {
        return new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=").test(doc.cookie);
    },
    remove: function (key, path, domain) {
        if (!key || !this.has(key)) {
            return false;
        }
        doc.cookie = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (domain ? "; domain=" + domain : "") + (path ? "; path=" + path : "");
        return true;
    },
};
var Utils = {
    merge: function () {
        var obj = {},
            i = 0,
            al = arguments.length,
            key;
        if (0 === al) {
            return obj;
        }
        for (; i < al; i++) {
            for (key in arguments[i]) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arguments[i], key)) {
                    obj[key] = arguments[i][key];
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    },
    str2bool: function (str) {
        str = "" + str;
        switch (str.toLowerCase()) {
            case "false":
            case "no":
            case "0":
            case "":
                return false;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    },
    fade_in: function (el) {
        if (el.style.opacity < 1) {
            el.style.opacity = (parseFloat(el.style.opacity) + 0.05).toFixed(2);
            win.setTimeout(function () {
                Utils.fade_in(el);
            }, 50);
        }
    },
    get_data_attribs: function (script) {
        var data = {};
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(script, "dataset")) {
            data = script.dataset;
        } else {
            var attribs = script.attributes;
            var key;
            for (key in attribs) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(attribs, key)) {
                    var attr = attribs[key];
                    if (/^data-/.test(attr.name)) {
                        var camelized = Utils.camelize(attr.name.substr(5));
                        data[camelized] = attr.value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    },
    normalize_keys: function (options_object) {
        var camelized = {};
        for (var key in options_object) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(options_object, key)) {
                var camelized_key = Utils.camelize(key);
                camelized[camelized_key] = options_object[camelized_key] ? options_object[camelized_key] : options_object[key];
            }
        }
        return camelized;
    },
    camelize: function (str) {
        var separator = "-",
            match = str.indexOf(separator);
        while (match != -1) {
            var last = match === str.length - 1,
                next = last ? "" : str[match + 1],
                upnext = next.toUpperCase(),
                sep_substr = last ? separator : separator + next;
            str = str.replace(sep_substr, upnext);
            match = str.indexOf(separator);
        }
        return str;
    },
    find_script_by_id: function (id) {
        var scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName("script");
        for (var i = 0, l = scripts.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (id === scripts[i].id) {
                return scripts[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    },
};
var script_el_invoker = Utils.find_script_by_id("cookiebanner");
var Cookiebanner = (context.Cookiebanner = function (opts) {
    this.init(opts);
});
Cookiebanner.prototype = {
    cookiejar: Cookies,
    init: function (opts) {
        this.inserted = false;
        this.closed = false;
        this.test_mode = false;
        var default_text = "This site uses cookies.";
        var default_link = "Detail";
        this.default_options = {
            cookie: "cookiebanner-accepted",
            closeText: "&#10006;",
            cookiePath: "/",
            debug: false,
            expires: Infinity,
            zindex: 255,
            mask: false,
            maskOpacity: 0.5,
            maskBackground: "#000",
            height: "auto",
            minHeight: "21px",
            bg: "#000",
            fg: "#ddd",
            link: "#aaa",
            position: "bottom",
            message: default_text,
            linkmsg: default_link,
            moreinfo: "http://www.examplesite123.com/cookie-policy/",
            effect: null,
            fontSize: "14px",
            fontFamily: "arial, sans-serif",
            instance: global_instance_name,
            textAlign: "center",
            acceptOnScroll: true,
        };
        this.options = this.default_options;
        this.script_el = script_el_invoker;
        if (this.script_el) {
            var data_options = Utils.get_data_attribs(this.script_el);
            this.options = Utils.merge(this.options, data_options);
        }
        if (opts) {
            opts = Utils.normalize_keys(opts);
            this.options = Utils.merge(this.options, opts);
        }
        global_instance_name = this.options.instance;
        this.options.zindex = parseInt(this.options.zindex, 10);
        this.options.mask = Utils.str2bool(this.options.mask);
        if ("string" === typeof this.options.expires) {
            if ("function" === typeof context[this.options.expires]) {
                this.options.expires = context[this.options.expires];
            }
        }
        if ("function" === typeof this.options.expires) {
            this.options.expires = this.options.expires();
        }
        if (this.script_el) {
            this.run();
        }
    },
    log: function () {
        if ("undefined" !== typeof console) {
            console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        }
    },
    run: function () {
        if (!this.agreed()) {
            var self = this;
            contentLoaded(win, function () {
                self.insert();
            });
        }
    },
    build_viewport_mask: function () {
        var mask = null;
        if (true === this.options.mask) {
            var mask_opacity = this.options.maskOpacity;
            var bg = this.options.maskBackground;
            var mask_markup =
                '<div id="cookiebanner-mask" style="' +
                "position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" +
                "background:" +
                bg +
                ";zoom:1;filter:alpha(opacity=" +
                mask_opacity * 100 +
                ");opacity:" +
                mask_opacity +
                ";" +
                "z-index:" +
                this.options.zindex +
                ';"></div>';
            var el = doc.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = mask_markup;
            mask = el.firstChild;
        }
        return mask;
    },
    agree: function () {
        this.cookiejar.set(this.options.cookie, 1, this.options.expires, this.options.cookiePath);
        return true;
    },
    agreed: function () {
        return this.cookiejar.has(this.options.cookie);
    },
    close: function () {
        if (this.inserted) {
            if (!this.closed) {
                if (this.element) {
                    this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element);
                }
                if (this.element_mask) {
                    this.element_mask.parentNode.removeChild(this.element_mask);
                }
                this.closed = true;
            }
        }
        return this.closed;
    },
    agree_and_close: function () {
        this.agree();
        return this.close();
    },
    cleanup: function () {
        this.close();
        return this.unload();
    },
    unload: function () {
        if (this.script_el) {
            this.script_el.parentNode.removeChild(this.script_el);
        }
        context[global_instance_name] = undefined;
        return true;
    },
    insert: function () {
        this.element_mask = this.build_viewport_mask();
        var zidx = this.options.zindex;
        if (this.element_mask) {
            zidx += 1;
        }
        var el = doc.createElement("div");
        el.className = "cookiebanner";
        el.style.position = "fixed";
        el.style.left = 0;
        el.style.right = 0;
        el.style.height = this.options.height;
        el.style.minHeight = this.options.minHeight;
        el.style.zIndex = zidx;
        el.style.background = this.options.bg;
        el.style.color = this.options.fg;
        el.style.lineHeight = el.style.minHeight;
        el.style.padding = "5px 16px";
        el.style.fontFamily = this.options.fontFamily;
        el.style.fontSize = this.options.fontSize;
        el.style.textAlign = this.options.textAlign;
        if ("top" === this.options.position) {
            el.style.top = 0;
        } else {
            el.style.bottom = 0;
        }
        el.innerHTML = '<div class="cookiebanner-close" style="float:right;padding-left:5px;">' + this.options.closeText + "</div>" + "<span>" + this.options.message + " <a>" + this.options.linkmsg + "</a></span>";
        this.element = el;
        var el_a = el.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        el_a.href = this.options.moreinfo;
        el_a.target = "_blank";
        el_a.style.textDecoration = "none";
        el_a.style.color = this.options.link;
        var el_x = el.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        el_x.style.cursor = "pointer";
        function on(el, ev, fn) {
            var add = el.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
                pre = el.addEventListener ? "" : "on";
            el[add](pre + ev, fn, false);
        }
        var self = this;
        on(el_x, "click", function () {
            self.agree_and_close();
        });
        if (this.element_mask) {
            on(this.element_mask, "click", function () {
                self.agree_and_close();
            });
            doc.body.appendChild(this.element_mask);
        }
        if (this.options.acceptOnScroll) {
            on(window, "scroll", function () {
                self.agree_and_close();
            });
        }
        doc.body.appendChild(this.element);
        this.inserted = true;
        if ("fade" === this.options.effect) {
            this.element.style.opacity = 0;
            Utils.fade_in(this.element);
        } else {
            this.element.style.opacity = 1;
        }
    },
};
if (script_el_invoker) {
    if (!context[global_instance_name]) {
        context[global_instance_name] = new Cookiebanner();
    }
}
})(window);
```

I load it in this way in functions.php in Wordpress:

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
<script defer type="text/javascript" id="cookiebanner" src="https://www.examplesite123.com/cookiebar.js"></script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

**It works fine.**

Now i duplicate the same javascript code and i called it **stickybar.js**. I add some modifications, also change **class** with name "stickybar":

**The code of the stickybar.js is** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u3r8hj50/) (i pasted it in jsfiddle because there is too much text for stackoverflow)

Then **i show this second bar** (stickybar.js) only on mobile device and after 8 second with this CSS:

```
.stickybar { display: none; }

@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px) {
.stickybar {
  display: block;
  animation: cssAnimation 0s 8s forwards;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  to   { visibility: visible; }
}
}
```

I load it in Wordpress with this code in functions.php:

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
<script defer type="text/javascript" id="cookiebanner" src="https://www.examplesite123.com/stickybar.js"></script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

**It works fine.**

**If i load one by one of this codes, they work fine.**

The problem is that when i load the two scripts together in this way in functions.php, only the first works:

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
<script defer type="text/javascript" id="cookiebanner" src="https://www.examplesite123.com/cookiebar.js"></script>
<script defer type="text/javascript" id="cookiebanner" src="https://www.examplesite123.com/stickybar.js"></script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

How can i load the two scripts together?

Comment: Each script needs a distinct "global instance name".

Comment: ID attribute in HTML should be unique - only one occurrence is allowed.

Comment: Look at `find_script_by_id` in both functions its looking for the SAME ID. However, you can't reuse IDs on the same page. So change the one in stickybar to stickybar THEN in your `wpb_hook_javascript` change the ID for the stickybar file to stickybar. Also in the stickbar file change the instance name in `global_instance_name` to something unique maybe `sbinstance`

Comment: Thanks! It works! I follow @imvain2 instructions. I also tried to put the two scripts into one script, but then how should i change the code in functions.php? In this case i "need to call" id="cookiebanner" and id="stickybar" from the one js file. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment thread on this question is semantically correct, you can only have one instance of each html `id` attribute, they *must* be unique, and your `find_script_by_id` methods are both searching for the same thing.

However, you're doing what's generally called "baking in" the scripts into your header which is at best, a faux pas, at least as far as WordPress is concerned. [Properly Enqueueing Scripts (and styles)](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) is very easy in WordPress, and your future self, web clients, and other people who look at your code will thank you for doing it.

It's not unlike how you're "baking in" the scripts now:

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
<script defer type="text/javascript" id="cookiebanner" src="https://www.examplesite123.com/cookiebar.js"></script>
<script defer type="text/javascript" id="cookiebanner" src="https://www.examplesite123.com/stickybar.js"></script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

But with a few things changed:

```
function enqueue_my_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cookie-bar', 'https://www.examplesite123.com/cookiebar.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sticky-bar', 'https://www.examplesite123.com/stickybar.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
```

Namely, it uses the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function on the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook. This lets you defer the script to the footer, load in the header, add version numbers to prevent caching issues, add dependencies, allows you to dynamically add/remove them programatically,gives them unique ID's based on the handle, and much more. (You do still need to update your `find_script_by_id` functions to use these new handles instead `cookie-bar`, `sticky-bar`, change the `global_instance_name`, etc. (more on that in a second)

With that said, if the `.js` files are on your server, you'll want to use [`site_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/), [`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/), [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/), or similar functions to grab the URL of the file instead of typing it out.  If you're using a remote resource, don't worry about it, but if they're on you're site, you should swap out the baked in version for that so you don't have issues if you ever move your site, and it allows you easier methods to edit the `version` to prevent caching problems if you change them.

Back to your variables, you may also want to replace your `find_script_by_id` type functions with [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) instead, to allow them to be more abstract and not rely on typo/duplicate prone element IDs, and instead reference the currently running `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thank you @Xhynk for your time and informations. I also tried to put the two scripts into one script, but then how should i change the code in functions.php? In this case i "need to call" id="cookiebanner" and id="stickybar" from the one js file. How can i do this?

Comment: That's a bit more in depth than I can really cover here - but why do you want to combine them into a single script…? Generally, keeping class-like files separate by name is a good thing, it makes maintenance *significantly* easier.

If you need the combined for other purposes, look into a plugin like [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) that will combine and minify your JS/CSS for you (provided it's been properly enqueued!). That allows you to maintain separate files, but serve a single cached file to your users.

Comment: For reduce the requests, only for optimization. I try with w3 Total cache, but after combine them, the script doesn't work. it does nothing, I leave them separated but only minified. Thanks again! You are great!

Comment: Curious. I try your indications with wp_enqueue_scripts, modifying only handle with 'cookiebanner' and 'stickybar', but scripts don't work.

With the following code they work. Anyway, thak you :):

function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
<script defer type="text/javascript" id="cookiebanner" src="https://www.examplesite123.com/cookiebar.js"></script>
<script defer type="text/javascript" id="stickybar" src="https://www.examplesite123.com/stickybar.js"></script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');